# Correct Construction and Destruction of Setter Dependency Injected Objects (maybe with qt)

Tags: c++, qt, dependency-injection, qt5

> *I am using QT, so maybe there are more advanced options or best practice approaches. But if there is a good, general C++ or language agnostic answer that would be awesomest!*

I try to get the construction and destruction of objects that are configured by *setter dependency injection* right and have struggles planning the life-time of the objects.

On a [German Microsoft Blog](https://www.microsoft.com/germany/techwiese/know-how/was-ist-eigentlich-dependency-injection.aspx) a nice metaphor to discuss the d dependencies, responsibilities and interaction between objects, that I'd like to adapt:

There is a Master-Gardener and a Apprentice-Gardener
The master want the apprentice to dig. In the beginning, the apprentice is being constructed having a shovel, so he can dig, but it is blamed, that creating a own shovel is too much responsibility for an apprentice.

Now in a second approach the master has access to a nice shovel factory, producing quality, testable shovels. He goes on, telling the apprentice to `digWith(testableShovel)`.

Now in the context of **Setter Dependendy Injection** I would let the master tell the apprentice `takeShovel(testableShovel)` (*setter*) and then `diggBoy()` to make him dig.

The problem arises, when the master forgets to tell the apprentice to take a shovel, as now the apprentice has no tool to dig.

To handle this case, I wonder - is it appropriate that the apprentice, upon construction creates his own very basic digging device (such as *a pair of hands*)? Or should that be done via constructor dependency injection (allowing both, constructor and dependency injection)? Is creating/bringing a pair of hands to much to ask of the apprentice, and I should rather have a `nullptr`-check?

---

Now, let's assume I have my apprentice created his own pair of hands, who will destroy them, once he picks up a shovel? And who will recreate them, once he drops the shovel? What will be destroyed, if the apprentice is to be put aside?

Answer (score 1):

To your first question: if the injected object is required by the target object to do its job, then it should be injected in the constructor. Otherwise, you'll have objects in invalid state after construction. Or, if you do the "basic" versions of some dependencies in the target, then you're introducing coupling that the dependency injection is trying to avoid in the first place. If, on the other hand, the dependency is somehow optional (e.g. a logger could be considered optional in some cases), then setter injection is completely fine.

Second, I would argue that the ownership of objects given to other objects via setter dependency injection is going to depend on the context. If the injected object is something that no others are going to use, then transfer a `std::unique_ptr` of it to the target. If, on the other hand, others are going to use it, then you're likely going to have a `std::shared_ptr` reference to it. The key here is that the use of modern "smart" pointers is going to signal and enforce the ownership of the injected objects.

Comment: I haven't touched the topic of smart pointers, yet. It is something left for me to read into and embrace, I guess. Thank you so far. As soon as I fully understand your answer (and there is no better until then) I will mark it as accepted. Until then (hopefully very near future) a *Thank You* and *+1* needs to suffice.